# Java: Get random line from a big file

Tags: java, file, constraints

I've seen [how to get a random line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218005/how-to-get-a-random-line-of-a-text-file-in-java), but the method stated there (the accepted answer) is running horrendously slow. It runs very slowly on my 598KB text file, and still slow on my a version of that text file which has only one out of every 20 lines, at 20KB. I never get past the "a" section (it's a wordlist).

The original file has 64141 lines; the shortened one has 2138 lines. To generate these files, I took the Linux Mint 11 `/usr/share/dict/american-english` wordlist and used `grep` to remove anything with uppercase or an apostrophe (`grep -v [[:upper:]] | grep -v \'`).

The code I'm using is

```
String result = null;
final Random rand = new Random();
int n = 0;
for (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(wordList); sc.hasNext();) {
    n++;
    if (rand.nextInt(n) == 0) {
    final String line = sc.nextLine();
        boolean isOK = true;
        for (final char c : line.toCharArray()) {
            if (!(constraints.isAllowed(c))) {
                isOK = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isOK) {
            result = line;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
return result;
```

which is slightly adapted from [Itay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218005/how-to-get-a-random-line-of-a-text-file-in-java/2218067#2218067).

The object `constraints` is a `KeyboardConstraints`, which basically has the one method `isAllowed(char)`:

```
public boolean isAllowed(final char key) {
    if (allAllowed) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return allowedKeys.contains(key);
    }
}
```

where `allowedKeys` and `allAllowed` are provided in the constructor. The `constraints` variable used here has `"aeouhtns".toCharArray()` as its `allowedKeys` with `allAllowed` off.

Essentially, what I want the method to do is to pick a random word *that satisfies the constraints* (e.g. for these constraints, "outvote" would work, but not "worker", because "w" is not in `"aeouhtns".toCharArray()`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in your implementation. You should read the line before you choose a random number. Change this:

```
n++;
if (rand.nextInt(n) == 0) {
    final String line = sc.nextLine();
```

To this (as in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218005/how-to-get-a-random-line-of-a-text-file-in-java/2218067#2218067)):

```
n++;
final String line = sc.nextLine();
if (rand.nextInt(n) == 0) {
```

You should also check the constraints before drawing a random number. If a line fails the constraints it should be ignored, something like this:

```
n++;

String line;
do {
    if (!sc.hasNext()) { return result; }
    line = sc.nextLine();
} while (!meetsConstraints(line));

if (rand.nextInt(n) == 0) {
    result = line; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see - so, when I don't call `nextLine()`, it just stays at the line until the number happens to be correct, hence its exponential slowing down. EDIT: I think I understand the second part too. Let me test this.

Answer (score 2):

I would read in all the lines, save these somewhere and then select a random line from that.  This takes a trivial amount of time because a single file of less than 1 MB is a trivial size these days.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        RandomDict dict = RandomDict.load("/usr/share/dict/american-english");
        final int count = 1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            dict.nextWord();
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to load and find %,d random words.", time / 1e9, count);
    }
}

class RandomDict {
    public static final String[] NO_STRINGS = {};
    final Random random = new Random();
    final String[] words;

    public RandomDict(String[] words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    public static RandomDict load(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        Set<String> words = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        try {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                if (line.indexOf('\'') >= 0) continue;
                words.add(line.toLowerCase());
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return new RandomDict(words.toArray(NO_STRINGS));
    }

    public String nextWord() {
        return words[random.nextInt(words.length)];
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.091 seconds to load and find 1,000,000 random words.
```

Comment: Oh, wow - that's really a lot faster (assuming you're not using some sort of supercomputer)! My current implementation takes about fifteen seconds to load 100 with 4GB RAM - I'll definitely update my code. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Its was using a 5 yo, core duo windows XP pc. ;)