# Time based reservoir sampling in java?

Tags: java, time, do-while

I've devised a way to do reservoir sampling in java, the code I used is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679544/1075247).

I've put in a huge file to be read now, and it takes about 40 seconds to read the lot before out putting the results to screen, and then reading the lot again. The file is too big to store in memory and just pick a random sample from that.

I was hoping I could write an extra while loop in there to get it to out put my `reservoirList` at a set period of time, and not just after it finished scanning the file.

Something like:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
timeElapsed = 0;
while(sc.hasNext()) //avoid end of file
    do{
       long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
       timeElapsed = (int)  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(startTime-currentTime,
               TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
       //sampling code goes here
    }while(timeElapsed%5000!=0)
    return reservoirList;
} return reservoirList;
```

But this outputs a bunch (not the full length of my ReservoirList) of lines and then a whole stream (a few hundred?) of the same line.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? One that, perhaps, works if possible.

Comment: Have you considered doing it concurrently, by sharing a concurrent collection between a reading and writing thread?

Comment: @DavidGrant I've not really dabbled in concurrency. I'll look into it.

Comment: This might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cheated. For now I'm outputting every X lines read from file, where X is large enough to give me a nice time delay between each sample. I use the count from the sampling program to work out when this is.

```
do {
    //sampling which includes a count++
}while(count%5000!=0)
```

One final note, I intialise counts to 1 to stop it outputting the first ten lines as a sample.

If anyone has a better, time based, solution, let me know.