# NumberFormatException while selecting random elements from a big file

Tags: java, random, numberformatexception

I have a very big file which contains user ids like this. Each line in that big file is an user id.

```
149905320
1165665384
66969324
886633368
1145241312
286585320
1008665352
```

So in that big file, I will have around 30Million user id's. Now I am trying to select random user id's from that big file. Below is the program I have but at some point it always give me this exception like this- and I am not sure why this exception is happening.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:59)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:510)
    at com.host.bulls.service.lnp.RandomReadFromFile.main(RandomReadFromFile.java:65)
```

Below is the program I have-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File f = new File("D:/abc.txt");
    RandomAccessFile file;

    try {

        file = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
        long file_size = file.length();

        // Let's start
        long chosen_byte = (long)(Math.random() * (file_size - 1));
        long cur_byte = chosen_byte;

        // Goto starting position
        file.seek(cur_byte);

        String s_LR = "";
        char a_char;

        // Get left hand chars
        for (;;)
        {
            a_char = (char)file.readByte();
            if (cur_byte < 0 || a_char == '\n' || a_char == '\r' || a_char == -1) break;
            else 
            {
                s_LR = a_char + s_LR;
                --cur_byte;
                if (cur_byte >= 0) file.seek(cur_byte);
                else break;
            }
        }

        // Get right hand chars
        cur_byte = chosen_byte + 1;
        file.seek(cur_byte);
        for (;;)
        {
            a_char = (char)file.readByte();
            if (cur_byte >= file_size || a_char == '\n' || a_char == '\r' || a_char == -1) break;
            else 
            {
                s_LR += a_char;
                ++cur_byte;
            }
        }

        // Parse ID
        if (cur_byte < file_size) 
        {
            int chosen_id = Integer.parseInt(s_LR);
            System.out.println("Chosen id : " + chosen_id);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Ran out of bounds..");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there any problem in my above code?

Comment: Code style note: if you `break` you do not need to `else`

Comment: Also, why do you `.readByte()` when you can `.readChar()`?

Comment: I would try to things:
1) Look at s_LR and see if the content is the expected one
2) If you have long numbers in there, maybe an Integer does not fit, then you would have to use Long for that. But your Exception points more to an empty String "", maybe you should check s_LR against that.

Comment: Is it new line at the end of abc.txt file?

Comment: I have also tried removing that as well but still the same issue.

Comment: I've tried to run your code and sometimes getting EOFException in the following piece of code "a_char = (char) file.readByte();"

Comment: I think your code is way to complicated. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218005/how-to-get-a-random-line-of-a-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code and found one additional error - you have to check cur_byte before read as follows:

```
if (cur_byte < file_size) {
    a_char = (char) file.readByte();
}
```

Otherwise you will get `EOFException`.

With your sample abc.txt I don't get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` exception.

But if I add empty lines in abc.txt I get this exception sooner or later. Thus the problem is with empty lines somewhere in abc.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Any unparsable String if you pass to `parseInt` method then it will raise `NumberFormatException`. Like empty String and also `Integer` can hold the maximum & minimum value an int can have, *2147483647* or *-2147483648*. And if value goes beyond of that then it raise `NumberFormatException`

```
If the string does not contain a parsable integer. ([Documentation][1])
```

Comment: OPs code definetly fails on the empty string and not a too high value. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Comment: Yes, my code is failing at empty string and that empty string is coming from here I guess `String s_LR = "";`

Comment: I think you are right @André, It is really hard to understand the whole, I tried to draw the general scenario

Answer (score 0):

It seems that s_LR contains an empty String.

From what I'm figuring this could happen if you have windows style linebreaks (\r\n) and hit the '\r' with the random seek. Then the break-conditions in both loops would apply, before any char is added to s_LR.

Sidenote: you are using a very atypical coding style for java. While it has no influence on your programm, it is harder to read/understand for other java programmers and therefore you may not get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Really that is look like you have empty string at the end of file or at the beginning of the file.

Or one of the numbers to long for Integer.

I see two solutions:

1. Add check for spaces and empty string for each element that you
   reads from file.
2. Change Integer to Long value.