# Producer Consumer in Java using threads never terminates

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter, infinite-loop, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Producer-Consumer problem to implement in Java, where I want the producer thread to run for a specific amount of time e.g. 1 day, putting objects in a `BlockingQueue` -specifically tweets, streamed from Twitter Streaming API via Twitter4j- and the consumer thread to consume these objects from the queue and write them to file. I've used the PC logic from [Read the 30Million user id's one by one from the big file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220892/read-the-30million-user-ids-one-by-one-from-the-big-file/17220973#17220973), where producer is the FileTask and consumer is the CPUTask (check first answer; my approach uses the same iterations/`try-catch blocks` with it). Of course I adapted the implementations accordingly.
My main function is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....

    final int threadCount = 2;

    // BlockingQueue with a capacity of 200
    BlockingQueue<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(200);

    // create thread pool with given size
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

    Future<?> f = service.submit(new GathererTask(tweets));
    try {
        f.get(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES); // Give specific time to the GathererTask
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        f.cancel(true); // Stop the Gatherer
    }

    try {
        service.submit(new FileTask(tweets)).get(); // Wait til FileTask completes
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    service.shutdownNow();

   try {
        service.awaitTermination(7, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that, although it does stream the tweets and writes them to file, it never terminates and never gets to the `f.cancel(true)` part. What should I change for it to work properly? Also, could you explain in your answer what went wrong here with the thread logic, so I learn from my mistake? Thank you in advance.

These are the `run()` functions of my PC classes:

Producer:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                try {
                    tweets.put(new Tweet(status.getText(),status.getCreatedAt(),status.getUser().getName(),status.getHashtagEntities()));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentTread.interrupt(); // Also tried this command
            }
        }

        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    ... // More Twitter4j commands
}
```

Consumer:

```
public void run() {
    Tweet tweet;
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.csv", true)))) {
        while(true) {
            try {
                // block if the queue is empty
                tweet = tweets.take();
                writeTweetToFile(tweet,out);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                break; // GathererTask has completed
            }
        }
        // poll() returns null if the queue is empty
        while((tweet = tweets.poll()) != null) {
            writeTweetToFile(tweet,out);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your Thread classes are handling the InterruptedException, if not, they will wait forever. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504172/how-to-shutdown-an-executorservice) might help.

Comment: I edited my question, so now it also includes the PC run methods.

Comment: Those look fine to me, I think you would need to take a thread dump with jstack and see where the threads are hung. You could find quick instructions http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2281