# I have a one million records in my excel file or text file, i want to insert that data to database using multi threading concept in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I already implemented this without threads concept, now to increase the performance i want to use multi threading concept, does this concept works here?
Please suggest better ideas to implement this.
I mean how to implement using Jdbc with multiple threads to insert the data from excel sheet to database.

Comment: *Please suggest better ideas to implement this*. **Batching**.

Comment: The bottleneck is probably not inserting in the DB but reading the Excel file and afaik Apache POI doesn't support multithreading. Also if you have a sequence and want to insert in order then this might cause trouble with multiple threads.

Comment: @maraca - Good points.  However, the fact that reading the spreadsheet is single-threaded doesn't necessarily make it >the< bottleneck.  It is only >the< bottleneck if your database(s) + their client-side thread(s) can collectively insert the data faster than a single thread can read it.  (If you are in that situation, you are in a GOOD place!)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220892/read-the-30million-user-ids-one-by-one-from-the-big-file/17220973#17220973) from awhile back - you'd use one thread to read in the data which you would put in an [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) (don't use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` or you might run out of heap space if the file reader is faster than the database writer), then use another thread to read data from the `BlockingQueue` and put it in your database.  (There probably isn't any benefit to using multiple threads to write to the database, but if there's any preprocessing involved then you can use multiple threads for preprocessing and a single thread to write to the database)