# How to randomly read a full row (including possible line breaks) from a big csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, random

I have a big CSV file whose size is not specific and maybe more than 4 GB.
I need to read some rows from the file **randomly** as test cases to do some tests in an application.

It's impossible to read the full file in memory because it will raise an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

*One solution* is to generate an array of some numbers falling in the range of the total number, then sort the list.
At last read from the file line by line according to the number stored in the array. So I could get a random set of full rows from the csv file.

Is there a `library` or `method` to read a full row from a `big csv` file `randomly`?

One solution:

```
// generate random numbers
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
    int random = faker.numberBetween(0, total);
    indexList.add(random);
}

// sort
Collections.sort(indexList);

// read from a file
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.csv"), "UTF-8"));

String line;
int lineNum = 0;
int pos = 0;
int currentNum = indexList.get(pos);
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    while (currentNum == lineNum) {

        list.add(line);
        pos++;

        if (pos == testCount)
            break;

        currentNum = indexList.get(pos);
    }

    if (pos == testCount)
        break;

    lineNum++;
}

reader.close();
```

Comment: Please add your tryings and codes that you implemented to ease the process of the solution.

Comment: Don't forget to initial JVM with higher heap memory by using -Xms variable

Comment: You can also generate a random number `p` between 0 (inclusive) and the size of the file. Then `seek` (e.g. using [skip()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29)) to the position `p` inside the file. From there, scan for the next EOL, then read and return the following line.

Comment: You could generate your array of randoms, create a BufferedReader and skip to each random number. Might be faster than reading line by line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random line of a text file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218005/how-to-get-a-random-line-of-a-text-file-in-java)

Comment: @walen: With CSV you can't read lines, though, you have to parse them because the line break could be part of a field.

Comment: @niaomingjian Fair point, but that means you're talking about "rows" not "lines". I'm editing your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) is an algorithm that comes to mind here. The nice thing about this is that you don't need to know how many items there are and you don't have to read the whole file into memory; just the next row as long as necessary.